# If the WiFi switched on, should it disable the ethernet?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

My friend having problems with her laptop and I am trying to help her via SMS.

She can't get her laptop connected to the internet via the Ethernet connection and there is no WiFi in the area.

Could it be because her WiFi is switch on, she is using an acer aspire. If she manually switches it off could that allow the ethernet connecttion to work? Or is it a missing driver? The cable works fine as her someone else tried it.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: I am pretty sure that "my friend's computer is not working...so what's wrong with it" questions are to localized.  I will go ahead and answer the question, my advice to you, have this friend seek professional support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could it be because her WiFi is switch on, she is using an Acer Aspire

It depends on the system's configuration.

> If she manually switches it off could that allow the ethernet
>   connecttion to work?

Have her try it...

> Or is it a missing driver?

It could be missing a driver....

> The cable works fine as her someone else tried it.

This would indicate its a configuration problem with the computer.  On my personal laptop I don't have to disable my ethernet network connection, when a cable is not plugged into it, Windows disables it automatically.

Comment: No computer I have used ever disabled the ethernet when you turned on wifi.  I would ask her if she's getting link lights around her port when the cable is plugged in.  Lack of them could indicate a physical problem on either end or in the cable itself.  Link lights **should** come one when both devices have power, even if the driver is not installed or is malfunctioning.

Comment: @techturtle - I should clarify my statement.  My network connection simply was not active when my wireless connection was active.  I don't understand the reason for the downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote you.  On the contrary, I had upvoted it.  My comment was meant to be an agreement plus a possible extra step in troubleshooting.  Might have been better placed after the question, not your answer...

Comment: @techturtle - I didn't actually think you were the one who downvoted my answer.  I was just upset a perfect valid answer was downvoted by some ninja downvoter.